# React API call for each selection option

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, api, filter

i have this function which receive select  option value.
furthermore, i have 3 select option (level , facility, host ). when i select option the value is send to this function.

```
private optionFilterHandler = (option: string, key: string | number) => {


// the key can be level , facility , host  
// whereas options are the values of keys
// for level option values are (debug , warning ,info etc)  
// similarly for host and facility have options values


        if (option || key) {
            this.setState({
                option: option,
                key: key,

            },
                this.filterHandler
            ); // callback function
        }
```

and then stored in the state as option and key

the problem is that i need all the three options to be send to API 
for example : API call should be like this

```
private filterHandler = async () => {

const response: Response = await fetch(
           'http://egrde-tvm-aso1.de.egr.lan:3000/api/v1/search',
           {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                   Accept: 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               },
               body: JSON.stringify({
                facility: this.state.option,
                level: this.state.option,
                host: this.state.option
       });
       });
}
```

so how should i send all the three options in json.Stringify({}) , as i am getting only one option value 
each time when i select option and how to check whether the option value belongs to level , facility or host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your state to have an object which gathers all the of the options. Then in the event handler, you could just assign the option to the property `key`. Additionally, perhaps you meant to use `&&` instead of `||` in the event handler?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        options: {
            level: undefined,
            facility: undefined,
            host: undefined
        }
    };
}

private optionFilterHandler = (option: string, key: string | number) => {
    if (option && key) {
        this.setState(
            {
                options: { ...this.state.options, [key]: option }
                // copies the old options object and sets the property `key` to
                // the value `option`
                // Uses "computed property names": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names
            },
            this.filterHandler
        );
    }
};

private filterHandler: Response = async () => {
    const { level, facility, host } = this.state.options
    // ⮤ object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

    if (!level || !facility || !host) {
        // Don't fetch unless all options are present (remove this if
        // it's okay to fetch with partial options)
        return
    }

    const response = await fetch(
        'http://egrde-tvm-aso1.de.egr.lan:3000/api/v1/search',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.options)
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the help cubrr the issue has been solved. :)